# Is this method chaining in java? I don't understand some part of chaining

Tags: java, spring-boot, return-type, method-chaining

I have a code like this below:

[image]

The code above is understandable. This is possible because each method (concat(), toupperclass(), trim()...) has the same object,which is "String name."

So my question is a code like this one below.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

em.createQuery("select m from Member m",Member.class)
        .getResultList();
```

[image]

They all have different return type. Unlike the one that I stated at the top, this one is different. how should I understand this? Can someone please help me understand this?

I tried to see if the same kind of questions have been answered, but unfortunately I couldn't find the exact answer that I look for.

Comment: does the code pass compilation

Comment: Please replace images with code and use the code editor for formatting/highlightening. Images can't be read by search engines or by TTS-engines. Users can't copy/paste your image.

Comment: Methods don't have objects, but parameters and return types. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

In the future please upload text files for your code instead of images.

The answer is that you don't need the return type to be the same. You just need to know what methods you can call on the object you have at each step.

In your case:

```
em.createQuery("select m from Member m", Member.class).getResultList()
```

You could also expand on multiple lines:

```java
TypedQuery<Member> query = em.createQuery("select m from Member m",Member.class);
List<Member> result = query.getResultList();
```

Because the `TypedQuery` class has the `getResultList` method you can call that method on the query object. But you don't have to have the `query` explicitly stored in a variable if you have no use for it after. That's why the one liner is preferred in this case.